# I am new to R programming language, I got this error when I want to do some microarray analysis. I would be glad if you could help me

Tags: r

I tried microarray analysis by R using `library(affy)` and `library(hugene10stv1cdf)`
and I got this error:

**datacalls.LUAD <- mas5calls(Data.LUAD)**

> Getting probe level data... 'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor
> standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

Error in getCdfInfo(object) :

> Could not obtain CDF environment, problems encountered: Specified
> environment does not contain HuGene-1_1-st-v1 Library - package
> hugene11stv1cdf not installed Bioconductor - hugene11stv1cdf not
> available

Comment: Dear Roxanna, please share a reproducible sample of your data by `dput(head(data))` so that others can use it and you will have better chances of getting relevant answers.

Comment: "package hugene11stv1cdf not installed " -- you need to install that package before trying to use it. Also, this might help: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/32905/